# How to update an entity with a dropdrownlist (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm a beginner in C# and I would like some help. I'm working on a web site project with ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework 6. So far, I never have to ask for help but I reached a deadlock.

My project's purpose is to list documents stored in a folder, register them in a database, and display every documents on a web page with a sortable table. Each document has a 'Referentiel' (a department or a categorie if you prefer) and should be editable. This is where I'm stuck. I made a view which contains a form to edit each field of a document. But, my model has a virtual attribute "Referentiel" which can't be update as easily as string attributes (the model fits the database with those attributes).

Here's my models, I've got Documents which own a Referentiel and Referentiels which own many Documents : a one-to-many relation. I implemented it with a list of Documents in the class Referentiel and a Referentiel attribute in Document.

```
public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // unique identifier
    public string Code { get; set; } // identifier of a document inside the company
    public string Titre { get; set; } // name of the saved file (pdf, word...)
    public string Type { get; set; } // specify the nature of the document
    public int Ref_Id {get; set;} // foreign identifier with the linked entity in a one-to-many relation.
    [ForeignKey("Id_Ref")]
    public virtual Referentiel Referentiel { get; set; } // company's department where the document belongs to. 
}

public class Referentiel
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // unique identifier
    public string Nom { get; set; } // name of a company's department
    public virtual List<Document> Documents { get; set; } // collection of object Document (N.B. : doesn't appear in the database)
}
```

I had to use a ViewModel to access both models in my view, so I made DocFormViewModel :

```
public class DocFormViewModel
{
    public List<Models.Referentiel> Referentiels { get; set; }
    public Models.Document Doc { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Référentiel")]
    public int SelectedReferentielId { get; set; }
}
```

My controller has two methods, one for GET requests and one for POST requests.

```
// GET: Documents/Modifier/5
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Modifier(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        vm.Doc = db.Documents.Find(id);

        if (vm.Doc == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(vm);
    }

    // POST: Documents/Modifier/5
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Modifier([Bind(Include = "Id,Code,Titre,Type,Referentiel")] Document doc)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(doc).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Accueil");
        }

        DocFormViewModel documentReferentielViewModel = new DocFormViewModel
        {
            Doc = db.Documents.Find(doc.Id),
            Referentiels = db.Referentiels.ToList(),
            SelectedReferentielId = doc.Referentiel.Id,

        };
        ViewBag.referentiel_Id = new SelectList(db.Referentiels.ToList(), "Id", "Referentiels", doc.Referentiel.Id);

        return View(documentReferentielViewModel);
    }
```

Finally, I use a dropdownList to collect existing Referentiel. The selected Referentiel would be chose for updating the edited Document. But when I submit the form my document keep its default Referentiel (In the database and in the view)

```
@model BaseDoc_OI_GRC.ViewModels.DocFormViewModel

<!--Some html-->
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedReferentielId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">        
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Doc.Referentiel.Id, Model.ReferentielItems)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Doc.Referentiel, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Enregistrer" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
}
```

I hope you understood me, I'm not a native speaker but I tried my best to stay clear. (some variable name are in French, it shouldn't be a concern but ask me if you want a better translation).

Thanks for reading, I would be very grateful for any solution. ;)

Comment: Try to add `db.Entry(doc.Referentiel).State = EntityState.Modified;` before `db.SaveChanges();`  You may need to flag the child entity as modified as well.

Comment: @Eric I thought about that too but didn't try. So, I changed my code but it throws an exception saying : `Attaching an entity of type 'BaseDoc.Models.Referentiel failed because another entity has the same primary key value.` If I ignore model's validation, it simply insert another model Referentiel into the database rather than updating each model involved.

Comment: There are multiple issues with your code. First your `Document` does not even appear to have a property to define the relationship (e.g. `int ReferentielId`). Next you have a view model that contains a data model (never do that and suggest you read [What is ViewModel in MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)). Next your `Modifier()` GET method returns an instance of `Document` to the view, but the view you have shown has `@model DocFormViewModel` so that would throw and exception.

Comment: Next your binding the dropdown to Doc.Referentiel.Id` but it needs to be `SelectedReferentielId` (ditto for `ValidationMessageFor()`) and the second parameter is `Model.ReferentielItems` which does not exist. Then you POST method has parameter `Document doc` when it needs to be `DocFormViewModel doc` and the list goes on. Its fairly clear you have not even shown the correct code because what you have shown would be throwing exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue yesterday. Thanks for your answers. I just used a method in my `Dal` class (Data Access Layer) for linking an entity `Document` to an entity `Referentiel`. It is much more easier this way and nothing throws exception (even if it didn't throw any before).

To sum up my new `Modifier` or "Edit" method in `DocumentsController` :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Modifier(DocFormViewModel viewModel){
    dal.ModifierType(viewModel.Doc.Id, viewModel.SelectedTypeString);
    dal.AjouterDocumentAReferentiel(viewModel.Doc.Id, viewModel.SelectedReferentielId); // English : AddDocumentToReferentiel(id_Document, id_Referentiel)
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Accueil");
}
```

Here is a sample of the view with corrected parameters :

```
<!--some-html-->
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    <!--some-html-->
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedReferentielId, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedReferentielId, Model.ReferentielItems)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedReferentielId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
}
```

My Dal class has methods to select and update entities, such as :

```
// Dal implements an interface IDal which extends IDisposable
public class Dal : Idal 
{
    private BddContext bdd; // BddContext extends DbContext with DbSet<Document> Documents and DbSet<Referentiel> Referentiels attributes

    // there are some attributes to fetch files from a folder but there're irrelevant to this issue so I skip them and their methods.
    // Obviously there are a lot more of method to edit, create, remove,
    // fetch or test existence in database/folder

    /**
     * This is the method I used in DocumentController instead of 
     * a direct access to the database with BddContext, now Dal does it instead
     */
    public void AjouterDocumentAReferentiel(int idDoc, int idRef)
    {
        Document document = bdd.Documents.FirstOrDefault(doc => doc.Id == idDoc);
        Referentiel referential = bdd.Referentiels.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == idRef)
        referential.Documents.Add(document);
        bdd.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Finally, this is the final result : (screenshots of both primary pages)

[Homepage where every documents in a folder are registered in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDKO4.png)
[Edit page for document with id = 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpMXF.png)